# Clarifying questions about MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

These are newb questions, I'm sure, so let's get this out of the way sooner rather than later: I'm new to MongoDB.

1. Does MongoDB guarantee that an entry will be saved?  E.g. if I have a process load 1,000,000 objects into MongoDB, am I guaranteed that they will all load properly or at least retry / raise an error when an error occurs?
2. Is NumberLong only for integers?  What if I wanted to use high precision decimals?
3. I know V8 / SpiderMonkey can be just as fast as C, but has anyone done any benchmarks for calculations of data in MongoDB?  For example, if I wanted to find the average over those 1,000,000 items I loaded in 1, I could probably do it in a map-reduce way with any programming language... have people run in to any trouble with using JavaScript with MongoDB?  What do you think?

Comment: any need for cross-posting this also to the mailing list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Most Mongo drivers let you insert data with "safe-mode" which waits for an insert to complete sucessfully, or raises an error on failure.  This is done behind the scenes  by calling the [getLastError](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command) command immediately after the insert.
2. MongoDB's underlying storage format [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) doesn't support high-percision decimals, only 64-bit floating point numbers.
3. JavaScript in MongoDB is single-threaded, and can be a bit slow.  Hopefully the JavaScript engine will be [upgraded to V8](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2407) which should speed things up.

Comment: A development branch exists that uses V8 as the JS engine. It will be out in the 2.x series.

Answer (score 1):

1. MongoDB follows eventual consistency model, which is defined as:

The storage system guarantees that if no new updates are made to the object, eventually all accesses will return the last updated value.

Thanks